# How to update Mutter to a new version in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, mutter

I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04. I am trying to update `libmutter-10-0` to version 42.2-0ubuntu1, but even after doing `apt update` and `apt show mutter` it shows:

Package: libmutter-10-0
Version: 42.0-3ubuntu2

I want to specifically update this package as there is a bug in the existing package. I am not sure how to update it as the package is very much available, if I see online [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter).

Comment: Suggested reading: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283)

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1421687/edit) to show the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 0):

libmutter-10-0 version 42.2-0ubuntu1 can be installed with `sudo apt install libmutter-10-0` in Ubuntu 22.04 if you have jammy-updates in your software sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. There should be a line in sources.list like the following line, and it shouldn't start with a `#` character which would make the whole line into a comment.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
```

After adding this line to your sources.list refresh the list of available software by running `sudo apt update` . Then install libmutter-10-0:

```
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install libmutter-10-0
```